# Pass data to template with redirect() in Statamic

Tags: laravel, forms, statamic

I've got a form in Statamic, and I want to pass some data back to it on submission to show a nice 'All good' message, e.g:

```
return redirect()
    ->back()
    ->with(['form_success' => true]);
```

Unfortunately the template completely ignores the contents of ->with() in the template.

Is there a way to get it to listen to with, or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Show your template; how are you trying to reference this `form_success` being sent from the redirect? `$form_success`? or `session()->get('form_success')`? One of those should work, the other will not (assuming Statamic hasn't modified that base Laravel functionality)

Comment: It's an antlers template. Adding {{ dump }} shows it's not set anywhere. I'll check the session though.

Comment: Ah, so Statamic doesn't use `blade` templates eh? Interesting, considering Statamic is built on top of Laravel. But yeah, in base Laravel, something like `view('index')->with(['var' => 'test'])` would make `$var` available in the view, while `back()->with(['var' => 'test'])` would make `session()->get('var')` available. I haven't worked with Statamic in _years_, so I don't know what's changed, if anything.

Comment: @TimLewis Somewhat late to the party, but you can use both Antlers and Blade templates in Statamic. Just name them *.antlers.html or *.blade.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you return like that from a `POST` route, I believe the `with` data is also available in the session.

So in Antlers, you should be able to do something like this:

```
{{ session:form_success }}
```

And to display something in your template depending on if `form_success` is available, you can do this:

```
{{ if {session:has key="form_success"} }}
    <p>Success!</p>
{{ /if }}
```

Hopefully this will work for you!